# iOS, subview size changes for no reason

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
 @objc class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

     var uiView: UIView!

     @IBOutlet weak var reactWrapperView: UIView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()


         self.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
         self.view.layer.borderWidth = 2

         self.reactWrapperView.frame = (self.reactWrapperView.superview?.bounds)!
         self.reactWrapperView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         self.reactWrapperView.layer.borderWidth = 5

         self.uiView = UIView(frame: (self.reactWrapperView.superview?.bounds)!)
         self.uiView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
         self.uiView.layer.borderWidth = 10

         self.reactWrapperView.addSubview(self.uiView)

     }
 }
```

self.view and self.rectWrapperView are created in a storyboard and they are same size as the phone screen as shown in the following image.

```
self.view : yellow
self.reactWrapperView : red
self.uiView: blue
```

As you can see, bottom blue border is not shown and `uiView` seems to grow in size.

I've been struggling for long hours, woner what could affect the size.

[image]

Comment: May be it is issue of size . Could you please try      to replace     self.reactWrapperView.addSubview(self.uiView) with  self.reactWrapperView.superView.addSubview, and set it alpha 0.5 to see reactWrapperView

Comment: try doing the same things in viewDidAppear.  Check if you still get the issue.

Comment: try to print the frame of all the views.

Comment: update your code in main thread or move to viewwillappear or viewDidAppear, reason ui not updated

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes, it seems to be the reason, I could accept if you move your comment to an answer.

Comment: @eugene - I added my answer

Comment: The same code is working at my end. Try compiling it again dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Viewcontroller UI is not updated (means not loaded fully), can you move  in **main thread** or else  move your code to **viewwillappear** or **viewDidAppear**, reason ui not updated.

**option1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         DispatchQueue.main.async { // or use sync


         self.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
         self.view.layer.borderWidth = 2

         self.reactWrapperView.frame = (self.reactWrapperView.superview?.bounds)!
         self.reactWrapperView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         self.reactWrapperView.layer.borderWidth = 5

         self.uiView = UIView(frame: (self.reactWrapperView.superview?.bounds)!)
         self.uiView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
         self.uiView.layer.borderWidth = 10

         self.reactWrapperView.addSubview(self.uiView)

     }
    }
 }
```

**option2**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


         self.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
         self.view.layer.borderWidth = 2

         self.reactWrapperView.frame = (self.reactWrapperView.superview?.bounds)!
         self.reactWrapperView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
         self.reactWrapperView.layer.borderWidth = 5

         self.uiView = UIView(frame: (self.reactWrapperView.superview?.bounds)!)
         self.uiView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
         self.uiView.layer.borderWidth = 10

         self.reactWrapperView.addSubview(self.uiView)

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the reason is:

```
     self.uiView = UIView(frame: (self.uiView.superview?.bounds)!)
```

did you already add the uiview to someView？ otherwise，why this uiview has its superview？